# Capybara issues with request specs using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, capybara, rspec-rails

Here is my request spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "user signs in", focus: true do

  before(:each) do
    create(:account_type)
  end

  it "allows users to sign in with their email address and password" do
    test_user = build_stubbed(:user)
    visit root_path
    click_link "Sign-In"
    fill_in "user_email", with: test_user.email
    fill_in "user_password", with: test_user.password
    click_button "Sign In"
    page.should have_content "Vitals"
  end
end
```

The issue is that I can see the request happen to log the user in, but when the user is logged in, the request is redirected back to the home page without an error message.

Here is my user factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email Faker::Internet.email
    password "password"
    password_confirmation "password"
    agreed_to_age_requirements true

    subscriptions {[create(:subscription)]}
  end 
end
```

subscriptions factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :subscription do
    account_type_id 1
    trial_expiry 30.days.from_now
    active true
  end
end
```

I am not sure why the request is failing and not signing-in the user.

Comment: print the page object to see the response. `p page` at the end of your test case

Comment: I tried that but it returns a `Capybara::Session` object... the weird part about my test is that I can see the `last_sign_in_at` attribute get updated in the log but then the user is redirected back to the `root_path`

Comment: print `page.html`. sorry about that. Refer to this for all the available methods -> http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session

Comment: It prints out the content of the home page

Comment: Is this the behavior that you get when you follow the same process in the browser on localhost, or is it test-specific?